# Rails 3.1 - How to separate CSS/JS between normal app and active_admin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

My application is deployed on Rails 3.1 and on Heroku.

**1.** In production.rb, if I have `config.assets.compile = true` only then active_admin works. However, in production, I want config.assets.compile = false for normal application CSS and JS. The active admin module will be used only by administrator so it can be slow.

**2.** Moreover, since I installed active_admin gem my normal CSS has got terribly disturbed.

Hence, I want to somehow split the CSS and JS of active_admin and normal application so that:

**1.** Only when I hit `localhost:3000/admin` then CSS and JS of active admin hits and that of normal app does not. When I am on any other URL, then CSS and JS of normal app hits but active admin's does not.

**2.** I can `config.assets.compile = false` to normal app CSS and JS while make it config.assets.compile = true for active_admin alone.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The good news is that you can have .compile set to false for both, and have both run fast!

Active admin uses its own manifests that start with 'active_admin'. By default these won't be precompiled by Rails.

To get them precompiled you need to add these files to the precompile array in production.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['active_admin.js', 'active_admin.css']
```

This will create the files in the /assets folder and allow you to set .compile to false all the time.

Don't forget to also set:

`config.assets.digest = true`

Comment: Hi Richard, since I did this its taking 1.5 mins per page to load in local. I posted a new question - can you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875968/somethings-wrong-with-assets-each-page-in-local-takes-over-1-5-mins-to-load